# Fresh install Ubuntu 16.04 : Not possible to boot Win10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mbr

Fresh install Ubuntu 16.04 on disk sdc.
Windows 10 is on sda.
During install, I chose to put grub on sda, I guess it was a mistake.
Grub does not see W10, and if I choose starting on windows hd through startup boot menu, it won't boot at all.
If I try to access my windows disk from Ubuntu, I get an error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/mike/DATA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/mike/DATA"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Opération non permise
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

How can I recover W10?
I do not really need to see it in grub options since I do not use W10 very  much and the bios boot menu is enough whenever I need to boot on W10.

Comment: BIOS, not UEFI? You should always install grub to same drive as Ubuntu install and keep Windows boot loader in MBR of Windows drive, if you have installs on different drives. You need to reinstall a Windows boot loader to sda and grub to sdc. Boot-Repair's advance mode can do that. Do not use autofix, that just installs grub everywhere. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair And you need to turn the Windows fast start or always on hibernation off. It will also keep any shared NTFS data partitions mounted if on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type on the terminal: `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4`.
2. And then remount again.